# Chrome Extension for FB only works on Initial Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension that is supposed to replace all elements of a certain class with something else. It works on the initial page load, but when you scroll down to content that was not included on the original page load, it does not.

I know I need some sort of event listener maybe that calls the function again when scrolling down or loading new content, but nothing seems to work. I've tried document.onload, window.onload, etc., even tried using jquery waypoints, but to no success.

Does anyone know the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Use MutationObserver or check periodically via setInterval.

Comment: SetInterval actually does not work in this case.

Comment: The other answers are good, and will probably solve the issue in this case. The answer which provides the most information about what you can do in an extension beyond those methods is: [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: Thank you- setInterval did work, I was just calling it incorrectly.